# How get current url address on mains browsers using UIAutomation?

Tags: delphi, ui-automation

I have a source that promises to get the active url from any browser using `UIAutomation`, but I have difficulty about how to call the `main` function and show result in a `ListBox` for example. Then, how would it?

Here is my code:

```
uses
UIAutomationClient_TLB, activeX;

var
Firefox_quebrou: boolean;

function GetURL(hTargetWnd: HWND): string;
  function Enumerar(pParent: IUIAutomationElement; Scope: TreeScope; pCondition: IUIAutomationCondition): String;
  var
    found    : IUIAutomationElementArray;
    ALen     : Integer;
    i        : Integer;
    iElement : IUIAutomationElement;

    retorno: integer;
    value : WideString;
    iInter: IInterface;
    ValPattern  : IUIAutomationValuePattern;
  begin
    Result := '';
    Firefox_quebrou := false;
    if pParent = nil then
      Exit;
    pParent.FindAll(Scope, pCondition, found);
    found.Get_Length(ALen);
    for i := 1 to ALen - 1 do
    begin
      found.GetElement(i, iElement);
      iElement.Get_CurrentControlType(retorno);
      if (
          (retorno = UIA_EditControlTypeId) or
          (retorno = UIA_GroupControlTypeId)
         ) then //UIA_DocumentControlTypeId
      begin
        iElement.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_ValuePatternId, iInter);
        if Assigned(iInter) then
        begin
          if iInter.QueryInterface(IID_IUIAutomationValuePattern, ValPattern) = S_OK then
          begin
            ValPattern.Get_CurrentValue(value);
            Result := trim(value);
            Firefox_quebrou := true;
            Break;
          end;
        end;
      end;
      if not Firefox_quebrou then
      begin
        Result := Enumerar(iElement, Scope, pCondition);
      end;
    end;

  end;
var
  UIAuto      : IUIAutomation;
  Ret         : Integer;
  RootElement : IUIAutomationElement;
  Scope       : TreeScope;
  varProp     : OleVariant;
  pCondition  : IUIAutomationCondition;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    UIAuto := CoCUIAutomation.Create;
    if Succeeded(UIAuto.ElementFromHandle(hTargetWnd, RootElement)) then
    begin
      TVariantArg(varProp).vt    := VT_BOOL;
      TVariantArg(varProp).vbool := True;
      UIAuto.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_IsControlElementPropertyId,
                                     varProp,
                                     pCondition);
      Scope := TreeScope_Element or TreeScope_Children;
      Result := Enumerar(RootElement, Scope, pCondition);
    end;
  except
    Result := '';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You first have to find the window handle of the browser before calling this function. Once you get that window handle, pass that handle into the function, and it returns the string. Then add that string to the list box. Also, it appears this unit requires another unit wrapping an ActiveX library, which I'm assuming you already have.

Comment: Yes, I already have this unit called [UIAutomationClient_TLB.pas](http://pastebin.com/a0b5J0FM).

Comment: So in other words, you have multiple questions here. The first question(s) you need to ask are how to get the Window handle of each particular browser.

Comment: I already solved my question. Solution: `procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label1.Caption:=  GetURL(GetForegroundWindow);
end;` Thank you very much for attention @Jerry Dodge!

Comment: +1 This is a v. useful example of UIAutomation using Delphi.  I had a couple of problems compiling it.  1.  Undeclared identifier UIA_EditControlTypeId - googling on it found a PasteBin entry http://pastebin.com/a0b5J0FM where a kind Mr.XRay has added a long list of constants to the Tlb import, though it couldn't find where he got them from.  2. Incompatible types on hTargetWnd in "if Succeeded(UIAuto.ElementFromHandle(hTargetWnd, RootElement))" requires cast "Pointer(hTargetWnd)".  After which it compiles and runs perfectly.

Comment: Here work very fine! get url address of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE, since them stay in foreground window.

Comment: @MartynA, those constants are defined in the UIAutomationClient.h header file which you will get with the Windows SDK. The author of that code most probably imported the *.idl file and made a few changes to it.