# Delphi 7 , Passing runtime field values to anther Program

Tags: delphi

I am trying to write a Payment Interface to an existing win32 program written in Delphi7.  I do not have the source code for the program. I simply want to send the run time value contained in the amount 1 field to the credit card machines API. 
Example Amount1 = 50.00

[image]

Amount 1 is a Tedit field

I have considered com, name pipes shared memory and so on. The examples I have found assume I have the source code. 
A dll or Ocx?

Any advise,  help or examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Carl, and welcome to SO.  Consider reading [ask] and come back to [edit] some additional detail into your answer.  A "blank slate" question isn't really suited for the site, as we're better off with explicit code and/or examples of your specific issue.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you wish to have your application "talk" with another third-party application. You also seem to mention an API. If there's an API, then you should be consulting with that third-party's API and their documentation. You don't get to pick and choose how you communicate with it - you need to follow their requirements. At this point, we don't even know *which* system it is, but we shouldn't have to, because this is not what Stack Overflow is all about. Just because the other app was also in Delphi doesn't mean you can simply "plug in" to it.

Comment: I also sure hope that screenshot of yours isn't showing a *real* customer's name and phone number. I hope you realize that once you've uploaded it to Stack Overflow, it's permanently here, and visible to many users, even if you edit or delete your question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437652/how-get-current-url-address-on-mains-browsers-using-uiautomation for an example of how to read the contents of FireFox's address bar from a Delphi app using MS's Ui Automation,  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Winsight or Spy++ to get the class information of the TEdit control.  Then use the FindWindow/[GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775460(v=vs.85).aspx) API methods to get the amount.  The trick would be getting the amount at the right time.  I assume you want to do so when the user clicks the Accept button.  There are various techniques that can be used to hook into existing applications that you cannot re-compile from modified source.  I would suggest you look at the [DelphiDetours](https://github.com/MahdiSafsafi/delphi-detours-library) project.