# Getting TcxTreeList data from external application written in Delphi

Tags: delphi, devexpress, external, sendmessage

I need to get all data from a TcxTreeList (a custom Devexpress control) from an external application. I know how to get data from standard controls in external applicatioins (i.e. Tree Views, List boxes, Memos, List Views and so on) sending the right windows messages, but I don't know how to do that for this kind of custom controls. 
Reading the documentation from Devexpress I can see the following class hierarchy: TcxTreeList -> TcxCustomTreeList -> TcxExtEditingControl -> TcxEditingControl -> TcxControl -> TCustomControl, but unfortunately I don't know what kind of windows messages to send in order to get data.

For example: in order to get data for a standard Tree View I send messages with parameters like TVGN_CHILD, TVGN_NEXT, TVM_GETITEM and so on in the right sequence.

Can someone suggest me how to get data for the TcxTreeList control?

Of course I'm asking this because it's absolutely impossible to modify the source code of the external application (I don't have it) or to rewrite it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do Devex Tech Support say about this?  They are far more likely to know if what you want is even possible than readers here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I didn't ask to them, just because I thought that the Devex Tech Support is for their customer only and not for other users like me. However I think it's a good idea. I'll try to ask them too.

Comment: Just to add some info: I wrote to Devexpress Tech Support, but they didn't answwer my question. They just suggested me how to install the trial version of their controls!!!

Comment: In that case, you might want to look into maybe using ui-automation, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437652/how-get-current-url-address-on-mains-browsers-using-uiautomation and my comment on it.

Comment: Thank you MartynA. I'll study that usecase, however It seems that I need more informations. The three controls I need to investigate derive from TCustomControl (no list, no treeview, and so on), so I will try to understand if UIAutomation could help me.

Comment: Unlikely that this custom control supports UI Automation. Probably you aren't going to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be in for a bit of an uphill struggle with this.  Try the following:

- Download & Install the Devex VCL Trial
- Create a new Delphi project, add a TcxTreelist to its main form, add two columns to the
  tree and, using the tree's Items editor, add two top-level item node to it and a sub-item
  to each of these.
- Compile & run the project, then inspect its behavoiur using WinSpy++ of similar.

Note that until you click any of the tree nodes, the cxTreelist has no internal windows (I mean
windows from an OS pov).

While you edit one of the data nodes in the tree, a window of class TcxCustomInnerTextEdit is created.
TcxCustomInnerTextEdit is declared in the Devex VCL source in the unit cxTextEdit.Pas and is a descendant
of TCustomEdit.  It has message handlers as follows (in addition to TCustomEdit's)

```
    { private }
    procedure CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
    procedure CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
    procedure EMReplaceSel(var Message: TMessage); message EM_REPLACESEL;
    procedure EMSetSel(var Message: TMessage); message EM_SETSEL;
    procedure WMChar(var Message: TWMChar); message WM_CHAR;
    procedure WMClear(var Message: TMessage); message WM_CLEAR;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
    procedure WMIMEChar(var Message: TMessage); message WM_IME_CHAR;
    procedure WMIMEComposition(var Message: TMessage); message WM_IME_COMPOSITION;
    procedure WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); message WM_KEYDOWN;
    procedure WMKillFocus(var Message: TWMKillFocus); message WM_KILLFOCUS;
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
    procedure WMSetFocus(var Message: TWMSetFocus); message WM_SETFOCUS;
    procedure WMSetFont(var Message: TWMSetFont); message WM_SETFONT;
    procedure WMSize(var Message: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
    procedure WMUndo(var Message: TWMSize); message WM_UNDO;
  protected
    procedure MouseEnter(AControl: TControl); dynamic;
    procedure MouseLeave(AControl: TControl); dynamic;
```

As you say how to get data from standard Windows controls, maybe these handler declarations are sufficient for you to see whether you could do what you want.

If you can select the node you want by sending a message to the app, depending
on what you wanting to do, you may be able to do it using the messages for those handlers.

Whether you could do similar using UI-automation, I'm not sure.  Generate an import unit
from UIAutomationCore.dll and experiment with what you can do with that, following the example
in [How get current url address on mains browsers using UIAutomation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437652/how-get-current-url-address-on-mains-browsers-using-uiautomation).

You'll notice that one of the enumeration constants in the import unit is
`TreeScope_Children` but I'd be v. surprised if you could use that to get at
the individual data nodes of the cxTreeList, but you never know.

Btw, TcxCustomInnerEdit implements a couple of interfaces

```
  IcxCustomInnerEdit = interface(IcxContainerInnerControl)
  ['{468D21B5-48AA-4077-8ED5-4C6112D460B1}']
    function CallDefWndProc(AMsg: UINT; WParam: WPARAM; LParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
    function CanProcessClipboardMessages: Boolean;
    function GetEditValue: TcxEditValue;
    function GetOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    function GetReadOnly: Boolean;
    procedure LockBounds(ALock: Boolean);
    procedure SafelySetFocus;
    procedure SetEditValue(const Value: TcxEditValue);
    procedure SetParent(Value: TWinControl);
    procedure SetOnChange(Value: TNotifyEvent);
    procedure SetReadOnly(Value: Boolean);
    property EditValue: TcxEditValue read GetEditValue write SetEditValue;
    property Parent: TWinControl write SetParent;
    property ReadOnly: Boolean read GetReadOnly write SetReadOnly;
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read GetOnChange write SetOnChange;
  end;

  { IcxInnerEditHelper }

  IcxInnerEditHelper = interface
  ['{35667555-6DC8-40D5-B705-B08D5697C621}']
    function GetHelper: IcxCustomInnerEdit;
  end;
```

and IcxContainerInnerControl is declared as

```
  IcxContainerInnerControl = interface
  ['{1B111318-D9C9-4C35-9EFF-5D95793C0106}']
    function GetControl: TWinControl;
    function GetControlContainer: TcxContainer;
    property Control: TWinControl read GetControl;
    property ControlContainer: TcxContainer read GetControlContainer;
  end;
```

but I have no idea whether you could invoke any of these interfaces from a separate Delphi app, even if they are of any use for what you're at.

I haven't studied the code of TcxTreeList as a whole, but I imagine that the image
of each data node is painted "virtually" by the treelist as a whole, except for the currently-focused node if any.  So, I wouldn't expect to find
co-existing sub-controls for each of the data nodes and other innards of the treelist.

Depnding or your budget, purchasing the Devex VCL library, which comes with full source, may be a good investment.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I already installed the Devex trial and using some WinSpy sw I can see very poor informations. Just as you told: when I click on TreeList I can see a TcxTextEdit like child windows.I cannot use the way to select every nodes because the main program must run without "external interference" on the client PC. I will study UI-Automation (I never worked with it), but in the meaningwhile I'm thinking to try some code or dll injection in order to work in the same memory space of original software trying to get something interesting...